# perl CGI, differences with param vs Var

Tags: perl

I do this in my cgi perl script:

```
my %USER_HTML_INPUT = Vars();
```

I noticed that if have an array of data assigned to one key it becomes like this:

```
$VAR= {'tempvalue' => '0�25�85�125' };
```

If i do @DATA = param('tempvalue'); It splits the values into the array.

How can I do the same operation without using param function.?

Comment: You can't. Calling Vars() converts the inputs to a hash and makes the values strings. What's wrong with using the param() function? It's generally considered bad practice to use Vars()

Comment: my perl script has to be multiple functional as a non cgi script as well. it would be easier if i had one top level call using Vars

Comment: `param()` works just fine from the command-line...

Comment: doesn't work:[mkdcelk03 gfong] scripts/> ./debug.cgi
Content-type: text/html
Expires: Wednesday, 27-Dec-95 05:29:10 GMT

$VAR1 = {};
[mkdcelk03 gfong] scripts/> ./debug.cgi?asdf=1
./debug.cgi?asdf=1: No match.

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, really want to do this without `param`, you could try something like (untested):

```
my $vars = Vars();
my %USER_HTML_INPUT = map { $_ => [ split(m{\0}, $vars->{$_}) ] } keys %$vars;
```

but slightly less ugly:

```
my %USER_HTML_INPUT = map { $_ => [ param($_) ] } param();
```

It is much cleaner, though, to simply use `param` on the parameters that you need.

Also read the section [DEBUGGING](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.50/lib/CGI.pm#DEBUGGING) of the CGI documentation to see how you can pass CGI parameters to a script using CGI.pm from the command-line.